# Relating flux and angular velocity of constantly rotating coil with induced voltage

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]
[image]

The flux and angular position of the graph has been recorded as shown in the graph.
and so is induced voltage and angular position.

and my teacher derived the relation between induced voltage and angular position as such:
[image]

My question is how he came to this relation. All he said was flux and angular position has a linear relationship we can write the equation for induced voltage as such.

If so does it imply that Flux= B*A*phi such that derivative of it will be (Flux)'=BA(phi)' and how can I say Flux =B*A*phi from the flux and angle graph?
I have tried to find linear equations for the different slope of the graph and couldn't arrive at the derivation he made.

My approach:

[image]

I find the function for every piecewise continuous graph which gives me the following result: Φ=-B∙A, Φ=((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙(φ-π/2), Φ=B∙A,
Φ=-((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙(φ-3π/2), Φ=-B∙A and let me find the derivative of flux with respect to angle first which gives me:

dΦ/dϕ=(2B∙A)/(π-2θ), dΦ/dϕ=-(2B∙A)/(π-2θ) for two slopes
and derivative of flux w.r.t time comes out to be:
(dΦ/dϕ)∙(dϕ/dt)=((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙dϕ/dt, (dΦ/dϕ)∙(dϕ/dt)=-((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙dϕ/dt, where dϕ/dt=2πn.
and it still isn't equal to what the professor derived.
I need insight on it.
Thank you.

Comment: " flux and angular position has a linear relationship". This is not the case for a coil of fixed shape rotating in a uniform magnetic field. Instead, the flux linked with the coil is proportional to $\cos \phi$, in which $\phi$ is the angle between the field direction and the coil's axis (that is the normal to the coil's plane, for a 'flat' coil).

Comment: yes, i thought of cos phi too, so you mean his derivation is wrong?

Comment: No, his derivation is not wrong; there shouldn't be a $\cos \phi$; now that you've supplied a diagram of the set-up I can see exactly what's going on. The magnetic field is radial and constant in magnitude except at the gaps between the pole pieces, so flux is always being cut at same rate.  But it's quite hard to visualise the flux through the coil in this case, and I'd go straight to the emf by using $\mathscr E=Blv$ for the two sides of the coil that are cutting magnetic flux, without worrying about flux. Your professor's blue graphs (dotted version) and formula for the emf are correct.

Comment: I remember him saying ''due to linear relationship between flux and angular position''. with E=Blv its straight forward. but I would love to know insights into his derivation.

Comment: Suppose that $\theta$ is the acute angle that the coil makes with the horizontal. You can see that none of the flux that crosses the annular gap between the magnet's poles and the central core between angles 0 and $\theta$, or between angles $(\pi-\theta)$ and $\pi$ is linked with the coil, that is none passes through the coil. Study the brown arrows to see this. Between $\theta$ and $(\pi-\theta)$ all the flux passes through the coil. But the amount of flux is proportional to the range of angles, $(\pi-2\theta)$. With a different datum orientation we can, I'm sure, get the prof's graph.

Comment: Sorry – no need for a different datum orientation. Angles measured anticlockwise from positive x axis. So, for example, when $\theta=\pi /2$, then $(\pi-2\theta)=0$, so no flux through coil, in accord with prof's graph.

Comment: and next thing is: he does neglect the annular gap or says there is no plateau on the flux and angle graph therefore continuous constant emf graph,for the derivation of his equation

Comment: You don't mean the *annular* gap do you? Don't you mean the gap between the magnet's pole-pieces? And I don't see that he completely neglects it: his flux graph has plateaus (or plateaux!)

Comment: sorry .he says ignoring the commutator gap.